# Inside isearch how to get mouse-2 clicked inside a frame to paste into echoarea?

Tags: copy-paste, isearch

When I search with [C-s](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Isearch-Yank.html), I can paste a search term (copied outside of emacs frame) with either `M-y` or `mouse-2` click focused inside echoarea. In xemacs it is enough to `mouse-2` click inside the main buffer to get the yank happen inside the echoarea. In emacs I have to `mouse-2` click inside the tiny echoarea for this to work.

**Is there a way to configure emacs to get `mouse-2` click in the main frame to replicate `M-y`-functionality when isearch (C-s) is activated?**

The only related custom configuration I have is:

```
;; paste where the mouse clicks
(setq mouse-yank-at-point nil)
```

but it doesn't seem to have any impact on what I'm trying to accomplish here.

I suppose I need to get `mouse-2` to be re-bound to `isearch-yank-kill` when in isearch, but I don't know how to do that.

And I read the [explanation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29204/20059) about echoarea not being a minibuffer, but I don't have enough emacs knowledge to do anything useful with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying `isearch.el` for some time I solved this by adding to my emacs config file:

```
;; override isearch-mouse-2, which requires clicking in the echo area
;; to yank, to have the same behavior clicking anywhere in the main
;; buffer
(define-key isearch-mode-map [mouse-2] 'isearch-yank-x-selection)
```

Now it behaves like xemacs. Fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you use [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus). User option **`isearchp-mouse-2-flag`** is `t` by default, giving you that behavior.

Someone who doesn't want the behavior can just customize the option to `nil`. `C-h v isearchp-mouse-2-flag` tells you:

> **`isearchp-mouse-2-flag`** is a variable defined in [`isearch+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch%2b.el).
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means clicking `mouse-2` during Isearch yanks the selection.
>
> In that case, you can select text with the mouse, then hit `C-s` to
>   search for it.
>
> If the value is `nil`, yank only if the `mouse-2` click is in the echo
>   area.  If not in the echo area, invoke whatever `mouse-2` is bound to
>   outside of Isearch.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: Thank you, @Drew. I can't make it to work though. I created `.emacs` with just `(require 'isearch)
(eval-after-load "isearch" '(require 'isearch+))
(eval-after-load "isearch" '(require 'isearch-prop))` and it doesn't do what you suggested. No loading errors, other than `isearch-prop.el: ‘condition-case-no-debug’ is an obsolete alias (as of 24.1); use ‘condition-case-unless-debug’ instead. [3 times]`. If I do `C-h v` there is no `isearchp-mouse-2-flag`. I do see other `isearchp-` symbols, so the package loaded. emacs-26.1 here. And `isearchp-mouse-2-flag` is in `isearch+.el` file.

Comment: 1. The `condition-case*` thing is a benign warning - ignore it. 2. You don't need to explicitly require `isearch` - it is loaded by Emacs. 3. You don't need the explicit `eval-after*` thing for `isearch-prop` - that library is loaded automatically if you load `isearch+.el`. 4. You don't need `isearch-prop.el` at all, for this question. 5. You can see that `isearchp-mouse-2-flag` is defined in `isearch+.el`. 6. Try just `emacs -Q` (no init file), then `M-x load-library isearch+`. I'm sure you'll have the variable - check its spelling. (The library needs to be in your `load-path`, of course.)

Comment: Thank you for all the items, @Drew - I have tried all to no avail. I load the library just fine as with (6). After peforming (6) I do 1. copy a word outside of emacs 2. Hit `C-s` followed by `mouse-2` click inside the main frame results in yank/paste of the copied word inside the main frame, same as it was before loading `isearch+`.

Comment: `C-h v` shows `isearchp-mouse-2-flag` to be set to `t`, but it doesn't work. It neither searches for the mouse selected word before hitting `C-s` (as the doc suggests), nor it allows pasting inside the frame to do the same, instead it just activates `mouse-2` which just yanks it into the main frame.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by speaking of frames, here. In the same window, do this: (1) Select some text with the mouse. (2) `C-s`. (3) Click `mouse-2`. The selected text will be added to the search string. That's all. You get the same effect by selecting text, then `M-w` (copy it to the `kill-ring`), then `C-s`, then `M-y`.

Comment: I guess you missed an important detail listed in my question - I need this to work with text copied outside of emacs, and not in the same window that is being searched. For inside emacs I don't need any extra features, `C-s`  already copies the word for me (+ optionally `C-w`/`C-r` for several words).

Comment: And to clarify the intention - it's much faster to select a word anywhere on linux and then paste it in a single click with middle button. I surely can go through Ctrl-C and then paste, but that's twice as many keys to hit, plus switching between mouse and keyboard. On xemacs I can select the word with the mouse anywhere on the desktop, then `C-s` with left hand and middle click in the main xemacs window/frame with the right hand - done. on emacs this only works if I click in echoarea - which is tiny and calls for an extra effort and time to focus there first.

Comment: Drew, looking more into this issue I also discovered that I can't use your `mouse3.el` as it prevents me from pasting with mouse-2 into the echoarea of isearch, which is unfortunate - as it's a very handy package otherwise. It happens if I just load the mouse3 package. Any idea why does mouse-3 messes up with mouse-2 behavior? Thank you.

Comment: There is no occurrence of `mouse-2` anywhere in `mouse3.el`; it should not affect `mouse-2`. Do you see the problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file) and you then load only `mouse3.el`? (Well, if you need `isearch+.el` to repro it then load that too.) If no problem then bisect your init file to find the culprit. If still a problem then provide (by email) a recipe to repro it - I don't know what you're doing. But first, see if you get the problem if, *after* loading `mouse3.el`, you evaluate the original defun for `mouse-save-then-kill` that is in `mouse.el`. Thx.

Comment: You were absolutely correct, @Drew. After bisecting it was isearch+ that was breaking the isearch's paste with mouse into echoarea. Thank you for helping me debug this and I can have mouse3 back!
Unfortunately, no other suggestions were made to help resolve the original question of this thread. Thank you for your support so far.

Comment: Glad you found out some more. But it's not clear to me what you mean by isearch+ breaking isearch's paste with mouse into echo area. Feel free to follow up by email if you think you've found an Isearch+ bug. Thx.

Comment: I sent you an email a few days ago as you suggested. I got the address from isearch+.el file, but I haven't heard back from you - perhaps that email address is not up-to-date? where do I find your latest email? And of course it's possible you received my email, but are just busy to answer it yet, in which case there is no problem. Thank you.

Comment: Got your mail. Haven't had time to look into it. Thx.